# Remove View and Reference in Array

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

Currently working on an video conferencing app where we add/remove subviews that have a video/OpenGL display when users join or leave. We keep track of the views in an array in the class. We're getting a BAD_ACCESS in GL ASM code when we remove the subview and also the array reference. Commenting out the `self.streams.remove(at: index)` will cause it to work.

```
func add(stream: StreamType, withView streamView: StreamViewType? = nil) -> Bool {

    if !self.has(streamId: stream.streamId) {
        let view = streamView ?? StreamViewType(stream: stream, userId: self.userId, delegate: self)
        let insertAt = view.stream.isLocal ? self.streams.count : 0

        self.streams.append(view)
        self.streamViews.insertSubview(view as! UIView, at: insertAt)
        self.delegate?.layoutManager(layoutOnly: true)
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func remove(streamId: String?) -> StreamViewType? {

    if let index = self.indexOf(streamId: streamId) {
        let streamView = self.streams[index]
        streamView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.streams.remove(at: index)
        self.delegate?.layoutManager(layoutOnly: true)
        return streamView
    }
    return nil
}
```

It seems to be a race condition of some sort. Any ideas?

Comment: Please include all of the relevant code. It's impossible to determine the issue from the code you have provided.

Comment: To answer this question we need more context. How do you create those views and where do you use them?

Comment: There seems no reason the code cause any error. Do you have any observer in the streamView you need to remove?

Comment: Added some additional code for reference

Comment: Is your value for 'index' valid?  If you print 'index' and 'self.streams.count', does it make sense during your crash scenario?

Comment: Yea unfortunately the index is inbounds on the array

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be an error in you openGL code when deallocating your view.

How is StreamViewType implemented?

Did you tear down the EAGLContext when deallocating your view?

Comment: Apparently in the WebRTC layer by google there are references to `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState` which is not available in iMessage. On line 196-198 of RTCEAGLVideoView.m in WebRTC it checks the app state and will run `[self teardownGL]` however this doesn't run in iMessage.